# How to find a clicked place on an SVG in Android?

Tags: android, svg

Suppose my app shows an SVG image ( converted from svg to drawable by svg-android library ) and once the user clicks on it, I need to know on which SVG group he clicked.

Suppose I need to pass the click coordinates to some sort of a parser, that would mine through the SVG file and return to which group they belong.

For example such SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Basic//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-basic.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">


<g id="RCTOP">
    <polygon fill="#4374B9" points="70,25 25,25 25,70"/>
</g>


<g id="RCBTM">
    <polygon fill="#B84545" points="30,75 75,75 75,30"/>
</g>


</svg>
```

[image]

should return "RCTOP" if it was clicked on, say, 35x35 or "RCBTM" if click on 55x55...

any ideas if there are such libraries somewhere or should I write it from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there no way to capture an `onclick` event from SVG itself?  eg. `<g id="RCBTM" onclick="clickRCBTM()">`

Comment: I believe not, svg-android library just parses SVG into a drawable.

Comment: @RogerTravis Did you find a way to handle clicks ?

Comment: @RogerTravis still nothing on the issue?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [PanZoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom)

, it can catch click event like this:

```
$panzoom.on('panzoomend', function( e, panzoom, matrix, changed ) {
  if ( !changed ) {
    // The user clicked or tapped and did not do a move with panzoom
  }
});
```